# MSI CustomActions generated by VisualStudio how to understand MSI table

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, vdproj

I desperately trying to convert .vdproj proj. into wix project, with same custom actions(reason is that i dunno exactly what all is installation supposed to do) - right now confused about this:

/installtype=notransaction /action=install /LogFile= /sd="[SourceDir]\" /td="[TARGETDIR]\" /cf=[CF] "[#_DF75DCA6_84B6_7B49_8F15_EAEE08D32EA4]" "[VSDFxConfigFile]"

No idea what [VSDFxConfigFile], and missing overall picture what is behind this Custom action generated by Visual Studio in WinService project.

If anyone give me clue about PROCESS i would highly appreciate it!

Update:
today i discussed installer requirements and one which is known among collegues is that it should be able to change .config file according to parameters - XML has whole configuration element tree  in it - and it should replace installed .config file - i just wonder if there is direct way to accomplish this in WIX

Moreover - .vdproj files already has some custom actions in it(which i guess aren't standard custom actions) - which calls some dll lib .NET installer component - which i guess changing .config according to parameters, but way it is happening isn't really clear to me. I used ORCA and MSI logs, however i still feel like Alice in world of dreams. Well thing is that also i'm unable to say what all parts of code called so that's why i still thinking call all CustomActions which are generated in msi file throught vdproj

Answer (score 1):

Ignore all that stuff. it's related to managed code custom actions, and managed code custom actions don't use the same framework in WiX - they use DTF. VS setups put several custom actions in that you don't need to worry about, such as checking for the NET Framework. So it's going to be pointless trying to transfer internal VS custom actions (because WiX has its own that do similar things) and because your managed code custom actions won't use the same framework of installer classes, Install methods etc.

VS setup projects install services with Installer classes, and WiX doesn't use those either - there's no reason to, because Windows Installer has built-in support for installing/starting/stopping services, so if your manage code is realted to that then again, ignore it. 
p.s. This may be useful:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/alexshev/archive/2008/02/10/from-msi-to-wix.aspx

Comment: today i discussed installer requirements and one which is known among collegues is that it should be able to change .config file according to parameters - XML has whole configuration element tree <configuration> it it - and it should replace installed .config file - i just wonder if there is direct way to accomplish this in WIX.